# Account class design using OOP paradigm

Tags: c++, class, oop

I want to design an account management system.I have an account class for storing the details of each account, a withdrawal class for storing the information regarding the money withdrawn from a particular account and an account list class with an array of accounts and member function add_acc,search_acc that searches for a particular account and show_acc that displays information of all the accounts. But before adding an account, I want to check if the account no. to be added, already exists or not. If it exists then an error message is displayed else the new account is added.But the show_acc function is not functioning, everytime it is called, it prints some garbage value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100
void Withdrawal(class Account_list &a);
class Account
{
    long long int acc_no;
    long double balance;
    public :
        void get_data(long long int acc,long double b=0)
        {
            acc=acc_no;
            b=balance;
        }
        void show_data()
        {
            cout<<"Account no. : "<<acc_no<<endl;
            cout<<"Balance     : "<<balance<<endl;
        }
        long long int get_acc_no()
        {
            return acc_no;
        }
        long double get_balance()
        {
            return balance;
        }
        void update(long double b)
        {
            balance=balance-b;
        }
        friend class Account_list;

};
class Account_list
{
    static int count;
    Account A[MAX];
    public:
        void add_acc();
        void show_acc();
        void search_acc(long long int);
        friend void Withdrawal(Account_list &a);

};
int Account_list::count=0;
void Account_list::add_acc()
{
    long long int acc;
    long double b;
    cout<<"Enter account number : ";
    cin>>acc;
    cout<<"Enter balance : ";
    cin>>b;
     for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            if (A[i].get_acc_no() == acc)
            {
                cout << "\nAccount already exists enter a unique account number\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        A[count].get_data(acc, b);
        count++;
}
void Account_list::search_acc(long long int ac)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if(A[i].get_acc_no()==ac)
        {
            A[i].show_data();
            return;
        }
        
    }
    cout<<"Account no. not found please enter a valid account no.";
}
void Account_list::show_acc()
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        A[i].show_data();
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
void Withdrawal(Account_list &a)
{
    long long int acc;
    long double amount;
    cout<<"Enter the account no. : ";
    cin>>acc;
    cout<<"Enter the amount to be withdrawn : ";
    cin>>amount;
        for(int i=0;i<a.count;i++)
        {
            if(a.A[i].get_acc_no()==acc && a.A[i].get_balance()>amount)
            {
                a.A[i].update(amount);
                cout<<"Amount withdrawn successfully\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Account no. not found or invalid withdrawal amount entered";
}

int main()
{
    Account_list A;
    char ch='Y';
    long long int acc;
    int i;
    while(ch)
    {
        cout<<"1. Add account"<<"\n"<<"2. Find account"<<"\n"<<"3. Withdraw amount"<<"\n"<<"4. Display information"<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter your choice : ";
        cin>>i;
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1: A.add_acc();
                    break;
            case 2: cout<<"Enter the account no. to be searched : ";
                    cin>>acc;
                    A.search_acc(acc);
                    break;
            case 3: Withdrawal(A);
                    break;
            case 4: A.show_acc();
                    break;
            default:cout<<"Enter a valid choice";
        }
        cout<<"Do you wish to continue?"<<" : ";
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
        {
            cout<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        else 
            break;
        
    }

}
```

The problem with my output -:

In the first run I entered the account no. as 123, int the second run I enter the acc. no. as 345 and when in the third run again I entered the acc. no. as 345, the error message was not displayed.

Comment: You probably do not want add_acc to be a member of Account. Bad practice

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 then should I declare it as a friend function?

Comment: No, just a normal function

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 then how do I access the data members of that class?

Comment: You seem to have problems understanding OOP. It seems that you think of a class as a mere namespace. The intention behind `add_acc` seems to be to create an account, but it is a standard member. What I think you want instead is a constructor. Are you aware that each `Account` object has it's own arrays? If not, you might want to reread basic tutorials for classes. In any case, a class that stores multiple accounts should not be named in singular.

Comment: Also instead of having raw arrays you might want to have a container for dynamic arrays like `std::vector`. Magic numbers like `#define MAX 100` are bad practice. Also, you should not do too many things at once - like user input in the account creation. And if the account numbers are used sparsely, consider storing accounts in a `std::map` or likewise. Wrapped in another class `Accounts`, that is, or directly in a `std::map<size_t, Account>`.

Comment: Also, calling something that initializes a value similar to your `CNT` method seems to be unreliable. Do people automatically know that they have to call that before they use the object? And it really could be done in a constructor. That is, if you keep on storing a count, for which there is no need if you do anything of what I wrote above.

Comment: @Aziuth actually here  I have provided with only add_rec function but I'll have to perform other operations on the Account class like finding an account no., balance withdrawal etc., which means I will have to use switch case to call each of these functions that is why I did not use a constructor. I may have to call the add_acc function later, and for doing so I'll have to declare another object (if I use a constructor) which I don't want to.

Comment: The thing is, it says `Account`, as in singular. If I see that class, I will think that an object of that class is a *single* Account, while what you have is a whole account system. If so, the class should be named `Accounts`. And you really should have a single class `Account` that stores the data of a single one. I assume that later it is to store more data? Like maybe the name of the owner?

Comment: In any case, I'd strongly suggest that when your bug is fixed, you take your code and put it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).